# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils' from utils import edit_distance

Tags: python, model

```py
from utils import edit_distance
```

> Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

from utils import edit_distance - I have imported it in a .py file. `utils` folder is in the same branch with `training` folder which contains .py file that I import `edit_distance` from utils:

[image: path_image]

Comment: Welcome! A hint: [You should not post code (...) project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/21350362). Could you please also specify the location of that `.py` file where import is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a hard import for file to see if it works like that first.

```
import path.to.utils.edi_distance
```

Though from what I saw (in the picture you linked) you are using the *init*_.py file, but it needs to have something inside it for you to be able to import what you want. You can have a look at how [python handles packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

In short, you need to import the file first in the `__init__.py` of the utils folder, so you can import utils like a module.

You can do that from a relative import, like so:

```
#utils/__init__.py

import .edit_distance
```

Why you need to do this? Well python, when you import a directory, tries to look for an `__init__.py` file, if there is one, it runs it to initialize the "module". So when you say `from "module" import "smt"`, that "smt" had been imported and then initialized in the `__init__.py` of the "module". Try to experiment on how it works.